# How to make typed command different colour to response in ZSH

Tags: zsh

In my `~/.zshrc` I have:

```
my_prompt() {
  PS1="%F{red}%D{%L:%M%p} %F{blue}%~ %F{yellow}$AWS_PROFILE %F{green}‚Üí %f"
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

How can I make the typed command (`ls`) green like the prompt and not white like the response?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, install [zsh syntax highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting). Then configure it in your `.zshrc`.

For instance, you can do something like this:

```
# Define the colours to be used:
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS=(main)
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=green'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[function]='fg=green'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[builtin]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[unknown]='fg=yellow'
# Turn it on. The following line uses my install directory. You have
# to replace it of course with your own.
source ~/other/zshext/syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

Comment: I had already syntax-highlighting installed, but ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[...] allowed to improve the command's look further. Small addition: `fg=` takes hex codes as well as words for colors. For instance: 'fg=#ff33e9,bold'

Answer (score 1):

this worked:

```
my_prompt() {
  PS1="%F{red}%D{%L:%M%p} %F{blue}%~ %F{yellow}$AWS_PROFILE %F{green}→ "
}

function preexec() {
  echo -ne "\e[0m"
}
```